# Complex Space Time - Mathematical Foundations

Tags: spacetime, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

I am really curious as to what the current research is in complex space time. Because in "The theory of Everything". Stephen Hawking does talk about imaginary time. Is there any mathematical background for this yet?
I ordered the book "Complex Geometry: An Introduction - Daniel Huybrechts"
It treats complex manifolds. Is this what I need to understand complex space time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The meaning of imaginary time](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46798/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123156/2451 and links therein.