# Complex solution in equation of motion

Tags: kinematics, complex-numbers

When I tried to solve some motion questions, I got complex numbers for time, displacement, etc. And my teacher said my answer was correct.

Is it possible to have a complex number solution in the equation of motion? What does the complex number mean in the equation of motion

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325683/2451